# Can't run Ruby on Rails with sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

When I'm trying to create db with `C:\Sites\qwe>rake db:create` I get this error:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"sqlite3", "database"=>"db/test.sqlite3", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (no such file to load -- sqlite3)
```

If enter this command I get:

```
C:\Sites\qwe>gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-sqlite3-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter, activerecord-sqlserver-adapter, activerecord-spatialite-adapter, activerecord-simpledb-adapter, activerecord-nulldb-adapter
```

Here's the full listing: http://pastebin.com/5pVzk6qW

I installed ruby and ror with railsinstaller.
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: could you paste your Gemfile?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that this has something to do with the sqlite3 gem failing to build due to a dependency.

Comment: please run `gem install bundle` and then `bundle install` from your application root folder and paste the output here

Comment: Thank you guys. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `gem install bundle` and then `bundle install` solved my issue.